# python how to convert <type 'str'> to <type 'dict'>

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a below dictionary defined with IP address of the application for the respective region. Region is user input variable, based on the input i need to procees the IP in rest of my script.

```
app_list=["puppet","dns","ntp"]

dns={'apac':["172.118.162.93","172.118.144.93"],'euro':["172.118.76.93","172.118.204.93","172.118.236.93"],'cana':["172.118.48.93","172.118.172.93"]}
ntp={'asia':["172.118.162.93","172.118.148.93"],'euro':["172.118.76.93","172.118.204.93","172.118.236.93"],'cana':["172.118.48.93","172.118.172.93"]}
puppet={'asia':["172.118.162.2251","1932.1625.254.2493"],'euro':["172.118.76.21","1932.1625.254.2493"],'cana':["172.118.76.21","193.1625.254.249"]}
```

***Code Tried***

```
   region=raw_input("entee the region:")
    for appl in app_list:
            for ip in appl[region]:
                   <<<rest of operations with IP in script>>
```

When I tried the above code got the error mentioned below. I tried to convert the str object to dict using json and ast module but still did not succeedd.

**Error received**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

As new to python unsure how to get the ip list based on the region

Comment: you can get a dictionary have format {Key: value},  string has indices by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem 1: your loop implies that app_list is a nested dict, which it isn't

problem 2: appl is a key to a dict, not the value of the dict.

this works:

```py
app_list={
"puppet": {'asia':["172.118.162.2251","1932.1625.254.2493"],'euro':["172.118.76.21","1932.1625.254.2493"],'cana':["172.118.76.21","193.1625.254.249"]},
"dns": {'apac':["172.118.162.93","172.118.144.93"],'euro':["172.118.76.93","172.118.204.93","172.118.236.93"],'cana':["172.118.48.93","172.118.172.93"]},
"ntp": {'asia':["172.118.162.93","172.118.148.93"],'euro':["172.118.76.93","172.118.204.93","172.118.236.93"],'cana':["172.118.48.93","172.118.172.93"]}
}

region=input("entee the region:")
print("")
for key in app_list:
  appl = app_list[key]
  if region in appl:
    for ip in appl[region]:
      print(ip)
  else:
    print("region not found in appl " + str(appl))
```

output

```sh
echo "asia" | python3 blubb.py
entee the region:
172.118.162.2251
1932.1625.254.2493
region not found in appl {'apac': ['172.118.162.93', '172.118.144.93'], 'euro': ['172.118.76.93', '172.118.204.93', '172.118.236.93'], 'cana': ['172.118.48.93', '172.118.172.93']}
172.118.162.93
172.118.148.93
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in each loop `for appl in app_list` appl will be a string and you are trying to index `appl[region]`, so you are trying to index the string with another string. But actually you just want to loop over the dictionaries `dns`, `ntp` and `puppet`, so you could do this instead:

```
dns={'apac':["172.118.162.93","172.118.144.93"],'euro':["172.118.76.93","172.118.204.93","172.118.236.93"],'cana':["172.118.48.93","172.118.172.93"]}
ntp={'asia':["172.118.162.93","172.118.148.93"],'euro':["172.118.76.93","172.118.204.93","172.118.236.93"],'cana':["172.118.48.93","172.118.172.93"]}
puppet={'asia':["172.118.162.2251","1932.1625.254.2493"],'euro':["172.118.76.21","1932.1625.254.2493"],'cana':["172.118.76.21","193.1625.254.249"]}

app_list = [puppet, dns, ntp]

region = input("entee the region:")

for appl in app_list:
  for ip in appl.get(region, []):
    print(ip)
```

Notice that 1) `app_list` is now a list of the predefined dictionaries and 2) that you should indx the region using the `get()` method for dictionaries, because the region might not be present in a given dictionary, so you can return an empty list as default. Otherwise you could run into a `KeyError`.

I hope that's what you were looking for.